Why is this method from the parent class functioning different between children classes?
I'm coding a text-based RPG and I set up three classes: a character class, a player, and an enemy. I have a method called "attack" that takes in a target, then removes from its health a certain number. It works perfectly when the player is attacking the enemy, but when the enemy attacks the player, it adds to the players health instead of taking away. Both attacks happen simultaneously, maybe that's part of the problem, but I don't see how that would be the case. I want both health stats to go down per attack sequence.
import random
class Character():

    #initialize a blank character
    def __init__(self, level, health, strength, defense): 
        self.level = level
        self.health = health * 100
        self.strength = strength
        self.defense = defense
                
    def attack(self, target):
        target.health = target.health-(self.strength * 1.5 - target.defense)


class Player(Character):

    #initialize the constructor of the player
    def __init__(self, level, health, strength, defense): 
        self.level = level
        self.health = health * 100
        self.strength = strength
        self.defense = defense

    def get_xp(self):
        pass

    def walk():
        pass

class Enemy(Character):

    #initialize the constructor of the enemy
    def __init__(self, level, health, strength, defense):
        self.level = level
        self.health = health * 100
        self.strength = strength
        self.defense = defense


import time
import random
from character import *

#creating a player

new_player = Player(1,10,10,10)

#establishing enemy stats
enemy_level_mod = random.randint(1,5)

if new_player.level > 5:
    enemy_level = new_player.level - random.randint(1,5)
else:
    enemy_level = 1

enemy_health = enemy_level * random.randint(1,4)
enemy_strength = enemy_level * random.randint(1,4)
enemy_defense = enemy_level * random.randint(1,4)

#running the game loop
while True:
    new_enemy = Enemy(enemy_level,enemy_health,enemy_strength,enemy_defense)
    while new_enemy.health > 0:
        print(f"Player Health is:{new_player.health}")
        print(f"Enemy Health is: {new_enemy.health}")
        new_player.attack(new_enemy)
        new_enemy.attack(new_player)
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Enemy has been vanquished")
        time.sleep(1)

Originally I didn't have a parent class, but I figured since they're both going to attack it would make more sense to have them be children of a class with common methods.

target.health-(self.strength * 1.5 - target.defense) Players defense is probably too high.

As a side note, when a child class __init__ is the same as the parent, it doesn't need to be implemented. In this case, you could leave it out since the child class doesn't do anything different and the parent's will be used.

With your current code, it is a possibility that enemy.strength * 1.5 < new_player.defense. What you can do is to set a minimum damage value with max(self.strength * 1.5 - target.defense, 1).
